# Как сделать смену сообщения через промежуток времени telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Хочу чтобы бот отправил в беседу в телеграмме сообщение, например: Сейчас 18:33:33.
И каждый например 15 секунд он его обновлял и было уже: Сейчас 18:33:48 и так далее.
Именно один раз отправил, а далее только обновлял и все. Как это реализовать на python telebot, подскажите пожалуйста:D

Answer (score 0):

Точно не подскажу, сам не профессионал, но возможно, вы это сможете реализовать через Pyrogram.

Для Pyrogram нужно будет получить api_id и api_hash, https://my.telegram.org/apps .

Пример кода 50/50 работает, все же лучше чем ничего.

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters
from pyrogram.errors import FloodWait 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import sleep

app = Client(
    "my_account",
    api_id = ВАШ ИД,
    api_hash = 'ВАШ ХЭШ'
)

# Команда type
@app.on_message(filters.command("type", prefixes=".") & filters.me)
def type(_, msg):
  
    orig_text = msg.text.split(".type ", maxsplit=1)[1]
    tbp = "" # to be printed

    while(tbp != orig_text):
        try:
            dtime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            dn = datetime.today() + timedelta(seconds = 15)
            dn = dn.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            
            msg.edit(dtime)
            sleep(15) # 50 ms

            msg.edit(dn)
            sleep(15)
            
        except FloodWait as e:
            sleep(e.x)

app.run()
```

Код выполняется с ввода сообщения в телеграм в виде .type TEST. В противном случае он не будет работать.

Идея не моя, была подсмотрена в этом видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpKODiSHL24

ВНИМАНИЕ, цикл не останавливается без `break`

Сильно не ругайтесь за ламерские ответы)